# Dockerfile copy to one folder up

Tags: docker

I have below structure

```
folder1
    Dockerfile
    start.sh
folder2
    config.ini
someotherfiles
```

inside the Dockerfile

i have added

```
COPY ../folder2/config.ini /
COPY ../somotherfiles /
```

Now when I build the docker, i'm getting error `file not found.`

how can I copy the files which is one folder up where the Dockerfile exists?

Comment: From where are you performing `docker build` ? `COPY` arguments are relative to where execute this command, not to the `Dockerfile`

Comment: ahh! thanks may be you are right. I was executing docker build in parent location. not in folder1. I will change accordingly and let you know.

Comment: Ok, let met write an answer then :-)

Answer (score 0):

`file not found` might be because you are not executing `docker build` from the same directory as your `Dockerfile` is.

`COPY` arguments are interpreted relatively from where you execute `docker run`, not from where the `Dockerfile` is.